# iterm2 Tmux integration: How to remerge windows back to tab; and X11 forwarding support

Tags: macos, tmux, iterm2

When I'm using iterm2+Tmux using

```
tmux -CC a -t 0
```

I can drag a tab from a tmux window so it becomes it's own window, but how do I get it to become a tab again? The only way I know of how to do it is through tmux dashboard by hiding/selecting all/reopen as tabs... is there another way to do this?

Also, does X11 forwarding work in iterm2+tmux integration? it looks like if I just do tmux it works but tmux -CC it doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is not an iterm2+tmux integration issue and more like a iterm2 issue... Here is the solution:

1. In iterm2 Preference>Appearance> Enable `Show tab bar even when there is only one tab`
2. You can then drag and drop the tab as usual

For X11 forwarding support, I just restarted (Cmd + Q) iterm2 and it works now.